# Draw Hexagonal Shapes using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Is it possible to draw hexagonal shapes using jQuery, HTML and CSS?

If yes how can we do that?

Comment: why do you insist on jQuery wouldn't a JavaSCript solution suffice (of which several exist)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery doesn't draw things. You could do this using CSS + HTML only. Here is a cool tutorial showing one way it could be done:

http://jtauber.github.com/articles/css-hexagon.html

Note: HTML / CSS may not be ideal for all situations. It might be better to look at using SVG instead.

Comment: The link you have given might work for me i will give this a try...thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

My best recommendation would to be use either SVG or canvas.

One example of a good SVG library is raphaeljs, check it out:

http://raphaeljs.com/

http://raphaeljs.com/animation.html

For canvas its quite simple to make shapes

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes